# How to upload a file in a test through Open Windows using Selenium::Remote::Driver Perl package

Tags: perl, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Below are the additional bullets :
 I can get my "button" with following code :

```
 $elem = $driver->find_element('//*[@id="file_uploader"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/span');
     $driver->mouse_move_to_location(element => $elem); # xoffset => x, yoffset => y
     $driver->click_ok('LEFT');
     $driver->pause(3000);
```

But after that, I can't get anything in Opened Window which appears . How is it possible to upload a file?

PS: Here screenshot of my Developper Tools.

[In Blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyaM4.png)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Selenium can not deal with OS dialogs. Therefore there is no way to deal with this dialog. This means you need to upload a file without opening it.
Luckily Selenium allows the user to send the filepath to the file input. This will upload the file.

In order to make it work you first need to find the input element instead of the button. It'll look something like:

```
<input type='file'>
```

Once you've found this element you can send the filepath to it like you would send any text to a textfield. I'm not sure how to do this in perl, but in Python you can achieve it like this:

```
element.send_keys('path/to/file')
```

You'll probably know yourself what the perl equivalent is.

Comment: Very good answer. You can improve it by adding a reference [to this documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver#upload_file) on how to do it in Perl. :)

Comment: i don't have input instead. How can i do differently ?

Comment: @Chaoui05 Any chance you could edit you original question and add the relevant HTML. It'd be easier to help you that way.

Comment: I can only add a screenshot cause my html is a layout and i use Developper Tools from Chrome. Is it ok ?

Comment: @Chaoui05 Ofcourse as long as we can see the code it's fine

Comment: @Chaoui05 If you are working on a public website that you can share so we can see the live version it would be even better.

Comment: i'am working in local for the moment . I would appreciate you see my creation. Sorry

Comment: @Chaoui05 What are the contents of the div with class dx-fileuploader-files-container? The div you opened is just the button. I'm thinking the input might be in the div under this.

Comment: It works right now with this input. I give you more explanations in following edit . Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's more specifical. I have two ways to upload a file in my web application :

First user can use a button 'select file'.

Second you can drop directly file .
By second way, and using "upload_file" method in Selenium::Remote::Driver package as it was proposed here, it's possible. I do that :

```
my $fname = "D:/dev/tests/selenium/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip";
my $remote_fname = $driver->upload_file( $fname );
    my $element = $driver->find_element( '//*[@id="file_uploader"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/input[@class="dx-fileuploader-input"]' );
    $element->send_keys( $remote_fname );
```

But not with my "button".

How is it possible ? I'm forwarding you additional screenshots here :

[In red 'button' and blue 'drop file'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cfcj.png)